# Can one prove the discovery of a P versus NP solution without actually revealing it?

Tags: p-vs-np

Suppose a person has proved that P≠NP. He wants to let the world know that he has solved the P versus NP problem but does not want to reveal that he has proved P≠NP as opposed to P=NP.

Is there any purely theoretical way to do so?

Also any practical evidence he can show to back his claim? (I'm not sure it this part is on-topic)

Comment: She or he will have enough trouble convincing the world without trying to hide this information.

Comment: @Thomas Really? I thought a properly written proof shouldn't be too hard to accept.

Comment: A straightforward application of zero-knowledge proofs should do the trick.

Comment: @OrMeir So what exactly will the zero knowledge proof be; that's what I'm asking

Comment: The NP statement would be "there exists a proof for P = NP or a proof for P \ne NP". A witness for this statement can be verified in polynomial time, so it is indeed in NP. Now apply zero-knowledge proof to this statement.

Comment: Let boolean cct  A be the verifier of s and cct B the verifier of Not(s) [ the ccts have the same input size chosen by the prover who obviously has a satisfying string for one cct]. Create cct C = A or B ;  and use the 'garbled cct'  ' (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/37993/42746) protocol to convince the second party that you do indeed have a satisfying assignment for  C.

Answer (score 3):

Or Meir’s comment is almost but not quite right, since it would be satisfied by a proof that P vs. NP is not independent even if the prover didn’t know which. A corrected version is “X is either the hash of a proof that P = NP or the hash of a proof that P $\ne$ NP”, where hash is SHA256, say.  Running that statement through a zero knowledge proof system gives the desired evidence.

However, if I was given such a proof, I would assign higher probability to someone having found a bug in the logical system being used.  It would be quite difficult to surmount that qualification in practice, since bugs in proof systems are fairly common.

Comment: I’m not claiming any particular cost limit, since as say it obviously depends on the size of the proof.